# Atom RegExp Search+Replace: Exact Match Symbol+AlphaNumeric with OR Ending Semicolon for Classes

Tags: regex, search, sass, atom-editor

**Why is this important?**

I am basically converting all of the colors on the web application to color variables. Now that I have a list of all of the colors, I am replacing close color matches to a main color variable name to consolidate a color code palete.

**Attempting?**

I am trying to find out how you would write a regular expression for an exact string match. The regular expression search & replace is for the ide Atom where I can search for specific classes without doing variable overrides; like $color_base1 and $color_base11. The default word match will not work in this scenario sadly because of the prior example.

Also, the end of the variable can end in a semicolon or no; so an or statement ending match.
Goal is to have an exact regExp match for variables names that are "$color_base1" & "$color_base1;"

**What I have so far? I know its bad.. I am learning.  :(**

I would greatly appreciate any guidance and advice on how to achieve this,

```
 ^\W$\bcolor\W__\blayoutBody
```

Comment: Maybe `\$color_\w+;?`?

Comment: when using this regexp I am pulling results like: $color_fontBase, $color__brand, $colo_fontBase12. I am only needing for it to return an exact match for $color_base. Thank you :)

Comment: You mean `\$color_base\d+;?`?

Comment: that one doesn't pull back anything at all sadly

Comment: Thanks for your help :) You are amazing my friend!

Comment: Do you thank me? :) I guess you got good help from ezig. Actually, the regex you need is `\$color_base1\b`. OR `\$color_base1(?!\d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\$color_base1(;|\b)`

https://regex101.com/r/bN4mA1/2

I was a little bit unclear on whether you wanted to match "$color_base11" or not. If you do, change the regex to this:

`\$color_base\d+;?`

Comment: You are my hero!! :) Your first response is corect; I did not want to match $color_base11